# Store spark partition RDDs in mutable Scala List for each spark dataset partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hbase

I'm trying to iterate over a dataset, and for each of its partition, trying to check if the row element is available in an HBase table. Once found, I'm storing that in list2 otherwise in list1. Using below piece of code to achieve the same.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HBaseConfiguration, TableName}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{ConnectionFactory, Get}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import scala.util.control.Exception.allCatch


val list1 = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String]()
val list2 = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String]()
val hbaseTable = "table"
val spark = new SparkSession.Builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

spark.sql("select col from table").foreachPartition{ partitions =>
 {
   val hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
   val conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hbaseConf)
   val table = conn.getTable(TableName.valueOf(hbaseTable))

   def foundValue(colFam:String,value:String):Option[String] = allCatch.opt{
     val get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(value))
     table.get(get).value().map(_.toChar).mkString
   }

   partitions.map{partition =>
       val cell = partition.getAs(0).toString
       val cellEmpty = foundValue("cf",cell)
     
       println(s"$cell exists")

       if(cellEmpty.isEmpty == true){
         list1 += cell
       }else{
         list2 += cell
       }
    }
 }
```

However, when I'm trying to access either of the lists, I'm getting no values although I can see logs for values if I use `println(cell)`, in the executors (YARN UI). I'm operating at executor level as the dataset is huge, and I'm not sure about the correct way of storing values to the list in the same area. Requesting your help towards achieving a possible solution.

Comment: You are creating a mutable variable in the driver context, it can not be updated from the executor unless you use an accumulator: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-accumulators/. Or you can collect the result of each partition creating a mutable list in each of them and then collecting the result.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting! I built a custom accumulator of type `Vector` and used it to store values. Followed below link for the reference:

https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Apache-Spark-2x-for-Java-Developers/blob/master/src/main/java/com/packt/sfjd/ch7/ListAccumulator.java
The logic is working now